# calling object resets/defaults the object values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
MapTool = function () {
  var keys = {
    markers: 'markers'
  }

  return {
    StoreValues: function(array) {
       $(self).data("markers", array)
  }
  LogArray1: function() {
    console.log($(self).data(keys));  
    console.log($(self).data(keys.markers)); 
    //Result: logged value is 'markers' (default keys.markers value)
  }
  LogArray2: function() {
    console.log($(self).data(keys.markers)); 
    //Result: logged value is an array of markers
  }
}
```

I do not understand why `LogArray1` defaults the dataKeys values when you first call `$(self).data(keys)`.
Is there anyone who can explain to me why this happens?

Comment: Because that's what [`data()` being called with an object](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-obj) does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method has different signatures. The documentation includes:

> `.data( obj )`
>
> **obj**
> Type: Object
> An object of key-value pairs of data to update.

So `$(self).data(keys)` updates the data with the "default" value for the `markers` key. It has in this particular case the same effect as if you would have done `$(self).data("markers", "markers")`.

Here is a demo of how passing an object to `data()` works:

```js
var self = document.body;

// First using the key, value signature:
$(self).data("country", "Canada");

// Then using the object parameter:
$(self).data({
    name: "Helen",
    city: "Toronto"
});

console.log($(self).data("name")); // Helen
console.log($(self).data("city")); // Toronto
console.log($(self).data("country")); // Canada
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In this snippet we see that the object parameter does not completely replace (reset) the original data -- only the keys that are provided in the object argument. The documentation says:

> Prior to jQuery 1.4.3, `.data( obj )` completely replaced all data. Since jQuery 1.4.3, data is instead extended by shallow merge.

Comment: So calling `$(self).data(keys)` would be the same as for instance calling `$(self).data("markers", "markers")` and `$(self).data("lines", "lines")` if `keys` had both a "markers" and a "line" variable? 
(The same as calling `$(self).data("key", "value")` for any and all variables on the `keys` object, effectively resetting the entire object? Did I understand it correctly?)

Comment: If `keys = { markers: "lines" }` then `$(self).data(keys)` is same as `$(self).data("markers", "lines")`. But you can verify all this based on the documentation. See demo added to my answer. There is no "resetting the entire object" though. Any other key/values remain in place.

Comment: No i meant more like `keys = { markers: "markers, lines: "lines" }`. As in, will calling `$(self).data(keys)` reset all values on the object back to default? I assume that is the case, I am just asking for confirmation to be sure :)

Comment: It's now all in the answer ,-)

Comment: Thank you, this clears my confusion regarding this issue. I will just have to remember to avoid calling .data(obj) even if trying to test things :P